React Native View Box Design
How can we achieve below red view layout using View of react Native, is there a way to get below layout with border radius of corners. Red box height is dynamic based on long text content.

have tried with exporting background as Image and put it as background image of view, but in that case image will get strach on case of long view and radius is not identical.
